# Referencing a variable from a Python file to a .kv file

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

On a python Kivy tutorial I learned that I could reference a variable from my .kv file to my python file. Is there a way to do this vice-versa?

(reference a variable from my Python file to its .kv file)

Answer (score 0):

I know there are lots of way to reference a variable from python to kivy. But what I did in my application is simply create a variable in a class then call it in the kivy file. You can see it in this code.

Python main.py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix import BoxLayout

class Window(BoxLayout):
    class_var = "This is the value that will reference from the Window class"
 
class KivyApp(App):
    app_var = 'This is the value reference from the variable in class App'

    def build(self):
        return Window()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    KivyApp().run()
```

Kivy kivy.kv file

```
<Window>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: [20]

    Label:
        id: lbl
        text: 'Sample Text'

    Button:
        text: 'Reference from Window Class'
        on_release: lbl.text = root.class_var
        # root is use to reference from the root class if you need to reference a variable from another class you can use app or the name of the other class.

    Button:
        text: 'Reference from App Class'
        on_release: lbl.text = app.app_var
```

In this program you will have a label in the top that changes once you press the button where you want which class in python file you want it to reference from.

Comment: Wow this is my first time using stack overflow and I didn't know it was this active and effective. Thank you for helping this 15 year old idiot :-)